# Pass null value as parameter in DataSet

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, dataset

I have fill method to get data from DB to dataSet that is like

```
Select * from table 
where (columnName = @parameter) OR (@parameter is null)
```

and in CS, its like

```
tableadapterObject.Fill(datasetObj.tableName, @parameter)
```

that works fine, but when I try to pass null

```
tableadapterObject.Fill(datasetObj.tableName, null)
```

It gives error.. **{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: columnName"}**

How could I Pass null value to parameter?? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the dataset designer to this table-adapter
- click on the properties of this query
- click on the `Parameters`
- change `Allow DbNull` from `false` to `true`.

[image]

(german IDE and other parameter, but you should understand what i mean)

Answer (score 1):

Change the property "AllowDBNull" to true. Please refer the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233762.aspx